Problem with Plotly plots on multiple Panel tabs
I have a Panel application that shows 3 different Plotly plots on different tabs. They display fine initially, but when they are updated, one or more of the tabs is blank. Here is an example that illustrates it. The three tabs initially show plots, but when the “go” button is pressed, one or more of the tabs will be blank. Am I doing something wrong? (The code was re-typed on a machine w/o Python, so hopefully there are no type-o’s.)
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

raw_data_viewer_tab = pn.Row()
histogram_tab = pn.Row()
cluster_plot_tab = pn.Row()

data = list()

for i in range(1000):
  num = random.random()
  data.append([i, i*num, i+num, i-num, i/num])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’, ‘e’])

raw_data_viewer_tab.append(pn.pane.Plotly(px.scatter(df, x=‘a’, y=‘b’, color=‘c’)))

fig_col = pn.Column()
for col in df.columns:
  fig_col.append(go.Figure([go.Historgram(x=df[col])]))
histogram_tab.append(fig_col)

cluster_plot_tab.append(go.Figure(([go.Scatter3d(x=df[‘a’], y=df[‘b’], z=df[‘c’], mode=‘markers’)]))

tabs = pn.Tabs((‘Raw Data Viewer’, raw_data_viewer_tab), (‘Cluster Data Histograms’, histogram_tab), (‘Cluster Plot’, cluster_plot_tab))

top_accordion = pn.Accordion()

template = pn.template.BootstrapTemplate(title=‘title’, sidebar=[top_accordion])

def update_plots(event):
  cluster_plot_tab[0] = pn.pane.Plotly(go.Figure([go.Scatter3d(x=df[‘a’], y=df[‘b’], z=df[‘c’], mode=‘markers’)]))
  raw_data_viewer_tab[0] = pn.pane.Plotly(px.scatter(df, x=‘a’, y=‘b’, color=‘c’))
  fig_col[0] = go.Figure([go.Histogram(x=df[col])])

update_button = pn.widgets.Button(name=‘go’)
template.sidebar.append(update_button)
update_button.param.watch(update_plots, ‘value’)

template.show()

